# monaca application can't connect to https urls on Android mobile

Tags: https, monaca

I am deploying mobile application using Monaca Clude IDE using angularjs
I get my data using https request connect to Restful API exist in other domain
with preview simulator every thing going good
but when I run that applicaiton on my android mobile the application can't get data from https url
**EDIT: I ADDED THIS CODE**

```
  function getUsernamePassword(username, password){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8444/api/checkPassword/" + username+"/"+password
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                return response;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
              console.log('login faield');
            });
        }
```

Comment: did you get any error message?

Comment: You are using a non standard HTTPS port, have you tried on the normal (443) port?

Comment: looks monaca forbids cross-domain requests.